# How to hide/secure session/encryption key in client side javascript from addon/extension

Tags: javascript, security, session, google-chrome-extension, web-storage

This is not a question if a web application can be safe/secure to use !!

But if I have a session or encryption key and like to hide it as good as possible on the client side with javascript - what is the best approach?

I wanted to use sessionStorage until I found out that any extension can read this from the content script at least in Chrome. In my view this is a big mistake from the developers as they hide the web pages javascript from the extension but allow it to see web-storage. Everywhere it is stated that the extension can only see the DOM but I do not think most people think that this also include web-storage!

So how can I secure a session key so it is away from reach of an extension? Unable to encrypt it as I then just need to hide the key. The problem is that the session have to be valid for all pages of the site so I can not just keep it in javascript as it is refreshed on each page load.

A cookie is in my view just as bad!

NB: Do not know if this is also a problem for other browsers

Answer (score 4):

An extension, given permission to access your page, can do anything.

A code injected as a `<script>` tag from a content script into the DOM will execute *regardless of your CSP* in the context of your page, will full access to your JS context.

That is not to even to mention `chrome.debugger` API.

So no, you cannot secure your client-side data from extensions that user consented to run on your page, just as you can't secure your data from the browser itself.

Comment: But it is quite strange then that the javascript code is protected. In my view web storage should also be included to allow some sort of "privacy"

Comment: It's not protected; it's isolated by default to prevent clashes with code, but an extension CAN break that barrier if desired; in short: extensions are protected from web, but not vice versa, as it's their job to interact with sites that know nothing of extensions.